# .Net Core 3 - api - XML and JSON format outputs upon URL request (.xml, .json)

Tags: .net, api, format, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm trying to figure out how setup content negotiations so the application servers both xml or json upon request.

I've tried multiple things you can find on the internet including [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-3.0) to no avail. ( you will kind of see that with my commented code ). I've tried putting all the options in .AddMvc, taking all the options out, etc. I have just not idea what to try next

Here is the initial part of the ConfigureServices call

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        //services.AddControllers().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
        services.AddControllers(options =>
        {
            options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
            options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<HttpNoContentOutputFormatter>();
            options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());

            options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat(
                                         "xml", "application/xml");
        });
        //services.AddControllers(options =>
        //{
        //    options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat
        //        ("xml", MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/xml"));
        //}).AddXmlSerializerFormatters().AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
```

Here is my attempt to set this up in the controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[FormatFilter]
public class PulpTestsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly DatabaseContext _context;

    public PulpTestsController(DatabaseContext context)
    {
            _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/PulpTests
    [HttpGet()]
    [HttpGet(".{format?}")]
    //[HttpGet(".{format?}"),FormatFilter]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<PulpTests>>> GetPulpTests()
    {
        return await _context.PulpTests.Include(b=>b.System).ToListAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well - in case anyone has my same issue, i made a change to the api to redefine the route and accept the format:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]    
[FormatFilter]
public class PulpTestsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly DatabaseContext _context;

    public PulpTestsController(DatabaseContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/PulpTests
    [Route("/api/[controller].{format}")] // <- Right here
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<PulpTests>>> GetPulpTests()
    {
        return await _context.PulpTests.Include(b=>b.SystemEntity).ToListAsync();
    }
```

I also removed a bunch of the boiler plate on the startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        //services.AddControllers().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
        services.AddControllers(options =>
        {
            options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
            options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;                
            //options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<HttpNoContentOutputFormatter>();
            //options.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerInputFormatter(options));
            //options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
            //options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat(
            //                             "xml", "application/xml");
        }).AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```